# Javalin 4: How to write properly check in call to Validator.check()?

Tags: kotlin, javalin

I am trying to adopt existing code of parameter validation from Javalin 3 to Javalin 4. It uses Javalin's `Validator` class. Here's the code I've got (rewritten):

```kotlin
  val messageId = ctx.pathParamAsClass<String>("messageId")
    .check(check = { it.trim().matches(Uuid.REGEX) }, errorMessage = "message id must be a UUID")
    .get()
    .trim()
```

And I am getting compile error for the `check()` call:

```
e: 
/home/ivan/.../SourceFile.kt: (53, 6): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments 
supplied: 
public final fun check(check: Check<String> /* = (String) -> Boolean */, error: ValidationError<String>): 
Validator<String> defined in io.javalin.core.validation.Validator
public final fun check(check: Check<String> /* = (String) -> Boolean */, error: String): Validator<String> defined in 
io.javalin.core.validation.Validator
```

I can't understand why there is an error. I assume I should have matched second overload of `check()`. How to write it correctly?

Note: I have read [Javalin 3 to 4 migration guide](https://javalin.io/migration-guide-javalin-3-to-4), which gives example like this:

```kotlin
ctx.queryParamAsClass<Int>("age")
    .check({ it >= 18 }, ValidationError("AGE_TOO_LOW", args = mapOf("minAge" to 18)))
    .get()
```

which I seem to follow, except I give it error message as string, but there's matching overload. So what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The cause was that second parameter of `check()` is called `error`, not `errorMessage`, i.e. correct code is like this:

```kotlin
...
  .check(check = { it.trim().matches(Uuid.REGEX) }, error = "...")
...
```